# Google Apps Mail Send Limit and Alternative

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail, jakarta-mail, sendmail, google-apps

I created a google app account, and I have been using its smtp server to send email with its admin account, but I notice that there is a sending limit of 2000.

I am using Java mail with smtp.gmail.com, username, password.
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=166852

Google suggests using the mail API, but I don't want to create a google app engine app to expose restful endpoint and then use their mail api. Is there a way to lift this limit? It seems like it works with Java mail, which is what I am using to send out mails, does this means that I am already using the mail api? but I am not running Java mail on App engine.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail

Please help! If there is no other way but to create an app engine app just to have the higher limit, I would like to know that too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you are not using GAE right now, but you are considering using it to increase limit?

Comment: Yes, the question is whether I can use Java Mail with the mail api but outside of app engine.

Comment: No, not directly. All APIs on GAE are obviously only available to code running on GAE.

Answer (score 3):

The App Engine Mail API can only be used from within App Engine. You cannot use your App Engine app as a mail server / relay server as there are no inbound sockets. As such a connection on Port 25 or 587 would not succeed.

As you suggest, the best approach to utilize the App Engine Mail API outside of App Engine is indeed to build your own REST API (or any other transport over HTTPS). On the App Engine side you would need a handler/servlet that calls the Java Mail API with the information supplied by the request. Keep in mind that your App Engine app is [only authorized to send from particular email addresses](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview#Sending_Mail), unless the request to send mail was directly initiated by another Google user.

Another possible approach would be to send a message to your App Engine app, and then resend the message to the final recipient. Once you [enable the inbound mail service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview#Receiving_Mail_in_Java) your App Engine app can receive messages at *string@appid.appspotmail.com*, where appid is the id of your application. You could send your mail in such a manner that the string part contains the final recipient. The inbound mail handler/servlet would then call the Mail API to send the message again based on the info in this string. Of course you could also include special instructions in the message itself and parse those out. Using this approach you will have more restrictions on the email addresses from which App Engine can send.

Keep in mind that the App Engine Mail API only supports a limited set of MIME types. Inline images via multipart/related and cid are not supported either. All inline images should be hosted.

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't really answer the question. I want to get the upper limit of 1,700,000, not trying to find another vendor to do the same thing.

Comment: Ah - I see what you are asking now. I'll update my answer to address this also.